# ServiceStack minimum configuration to get Redis Pub/Sub working between multiple Web sites/services

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

Let's say for sake of argument I have 3 web service hosts running, and only one of them has registered any handlers (which I think equates to subscribing to the channel/topic) e.g.

```
var mqService = new RedisMqServer(container.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>())
{
    DisablePriorityQueues = true
};
container.Register<IMessageService>(mqService);
container.Register(mqService.MessageFactory);

mqService.RegisterHandler<OutboundInitiateCallInfo>(ServiceController.ExecuteMessage);
mqService.RegisterHandler<DirectMailAssignmentInfo>(ServiceController.ExecuteMessage);

mqService.Start();
```

Now my question is, "Do I need to construct the other app hosts in the same fashion if they only publish??" e.g.

```
var mqService = new RedisMqServer(container.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>())
{
    DisablePriorityQueues = true
};
container.Register<IMessageService>(mqService);
container.Register(mqService.MessageFactory);

mqService.Start(); <=== Do I need to start the service, or is the MessageFactory registration enough?
```

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum code for a publisher is just:

```
var redisManager = container.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>();

using (var mqProducer = new RedisMessageProducer(redisManager))
{
    mqProducer.Publish(new Msg { ... });
}
```

You could also use a MessageFactory:

```
var msgFactory = new RedisMessageFactory(redisMangager);

using (var mqClient = msgFactory.CreateMessageQueueClient())
{
    mqClient.Publish(new Msg { ... });
}
```